# Problems converting from char to string

Tags: java

I tried creating a little programm, that randomly puts chars together (in this case 2 to keep it simple) until it gets the requested combination (here: "ab"). But unfortunately I seem to have trouble adding the char "rand" onto the string "string", because the comparison in the while-loop doesn't seem to work even though it has the right combination.
Could it be, that Java adds invisible characters when you create a String?
How can I add the char properly?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String string = "";
    String comp = "ab";
    int counter = 0;
    char rand;

    while (string != comp) {
        string = "";
        for (int i = 1; i <= comp.length(); i++) {
            rand = (char) Math.floor(Math.random() *26 + 97);
            //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, rand);
            string += rand;
            //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, string);
        }
        //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, string + ", " + counter);
        counter++;
        System.out.println(string + ", " + counter);
    }

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, string);
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Achieved after " + counter + " tries");
}
```

Comment: while(!string.equals(comp))

Answer (score 1):

use the String `equals` method to compare Strings in Java

```
while (!string.equals(comp)) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I knew it had to be some stupid, simple mistake on my side.